# Passing args to defined bash functions through GNU parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

Let me show you a snippet of my Bash script and how I try to run parallel:

```
    parallel -a "$file" \
            -k \
            -j8 \
            --block 100M \
            --pipepart \
            --bar \
            --will-cite \
            _fix_col_number {} | _unify_null_value {} >> "$OUTPUT_DIR/$new_filename"
```

So, I am basically trying to process each line in a file in parallel using Bash functions defined inside my script. However, I am not sure how to pass each line to my defined functions "_fix_col_number" and "_unify_null_value". Whatever I do, nothing gets passed to the functions.

I am exporting the functions like this in my script:

```
declare -x NUM_OF_COLUMNS
export -f _fix_col_number
export -f _add_tabs
export -f _unify_null_value
```

The mentioned functions are:

```
_unify_null_value()
{
    _string=$(echo "$1" | perl -0777 -pe "s/(?<=\t)\.(?=\s)//g" | \
              perl -0777 -pe "s/(?<=\t)NA(?=\s)//g" | \
              perl -0777 -pe "s/(?<=\t)No Info(?=\s)//g")
    echo "$_string"
}
```

```
_add_tabs()
{
    _tabs=""

    for (( c=1; c<=$1; c++ ))
    do
        _tabs="$_tabs\t"
    done

    echo -e "$_tabs"
}
```

```
_fix_col_number()
{
    line_cols=$(echo "$1" | awk -F"\t" '{ print NF }')

    if [[ $line_cols -gt $NUM_OF_COLUMNS ]]; then
        new_line=$(echo "$1" | cut -f1-"$NUM_OF_COLUMNS")
        echo -e "$new_line\n"
    elif [[ $line_cols -lt $NUM_OF_COLUMNS ]]; then
        missing_columns=$(( NUM_OF_COLUMNS - line_cols ))
        new_line="${1//$'\n'/}$(_add_tabs $missing_columns)"
        echo -e "$new_line\n"
    else
        echo -e "$1"
    fi
}
```

I tried removing {} from parallel. Not really sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As @Socowi says, you probably have the wrong approach. Maybe try taking a step back and showing a sample input file and corresponding output file and you'll probably find `awk` or `perl` can process it considerably faster than you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems in the invocation plus additional problems with the functions:

1. With `--pipepart` there are no arguments. The blocks read from `-a file` are passed over stdin to your functions. Try the following commands to confirm this:
   `seq 9 > file`
   `parallel -a file --pipepart echo`
   `parallel -a file --pipepart cat`
   Theoretically, you could read stdin into a variable and pass that variable to your functions, ...
   `parallel -a file --pipepart 'b=$(cat); someFunction "$b"'`
   ... but I wouldn't recommend it, especially since your blocks are 100MB each.
2. Bash interprets the pipe `|` in your command before `parallel` even sees it. To run a pipe, quote the entire command:
   `parallel ... 'b=$(cat); _fix_col_number "$b" | _unify_null_value "$b"' >> ...`
3. `_fix_col_number` seems to assume its argument to be a single line, but receives 100MB blocks instead.
4. `_unify_null_value` does not read stdin, so `_fix_col_number {} | _unify_null_value {}` is equivalent to `_unify_null_value {}`.

That being said, your functions can be drastically improved. They start a lot of processes which becomes incredibly expensive for larger files. You can do some trivial improvements like combining `perl ... | perl ... | perl ...` into a single `perl`. Likewise, instead of storing everything in variables, you can process stdin directly: Just use `f() { cmd1 | cmd2; }` instead of `f() { var=$(echo "$1" | cmd1); var=$(echo "$var" | cmd2); echo "$var"; }`.
However, don't waste time on small things like these. A complete rewrite in `sed`, `awk`, or `perl` is easy and should outperfom every optimization on the existing functions.

Try

```
n="INSERT NUMBER OF COLUMNS HERE"
tabs=$(perl -e "print \"\t\" x $n")
perl -pe "s/\r?\$/$tabs/; s/\t\K(\.|NA|No Info)(?=\s)//g;" file |
cut -f "1-$n"
```

If you still find this too slow, leave out `file`; pack the command into a function, export that function and then call `parallel -a file -k --pipepart nameOfTheFunction`. The option `--block` is not necessary as `pipepart` will evenly split the input based on the number of jobs (can be specified with `-j`).

Comment: You are right, it looks like I have to read the parallel manual better. I clearly misunderstood the concepts of block.

Comment: @user1261558 No problem. That is what stackoverflow is for. Also, the documentation was a bit tricky here since neither `--pipepart` nor `--block` mentioned this behavior directly; you had to read `--pipe` to understand this. BTW: Did you try the `sed` script I added in my last edit? Did it work for you?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did try, it works, but I am not getting an identical file as original (created by another script which I try to refactor). I will use your function and see if I can found out exactly why it differs.

Comment: Oh, I see, last column is not there. Could you explain a bit your regex, I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237936/discussion-between-user1261558-and-socowi).